# asyncpg: How to construct SET strings with parameters

Tags: postgresql, asyncpg

What is the correct way to pass in parameters in a SET query?

this will return `asyncpg.exceptions.PostgresSyntaxError: syntax error at or near "$1"`

```py
import asyncio

import asyncpg


async def main():
    conn = await asyncpg.connect(user="xx", password="yy", host="127.0.0.1", database="my_db")

    # works
    await conn.execute("select $1", "1")

    identity = "arn:aws:sts::123456:assumed-role/thing_1"

    # fails
    await conn.execute("set session iam.identity = $1", identity)

asyncio.run(main())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

asyncpg has a function for this:

```py
await conn.execute("select set_config('iam.identity', $1, false)", identity)
```

Comment: To be precise, this is postgres function https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-SET
from https://github.com/MagicStack/asyncpg/discussions/883